# ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found

Tags: python, imagemagick, magickwand

The below shows me trying to run my code with a response that the MagickWand shared library is not found and that imagemagick library is not installed. So I try to install, but it shows it's already installed? Any advice for next steps to trouble shoot?

```
python /Users/osx/Downloads/pdf_manage/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/osx/Downloads/pdf_manage/main.py", line 3, in <module>
from src.pdf_utils import PdfUtils
File "/Users/osx/Downloads/pdf_manage/src/pdf_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
from wand.image import Image as WandImage
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 206, in <module>
'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
brew install freetype imagemagick
osx:~ osx$ brew install imageMagick
Warning: imagemagick 7.0.7-26 is already installed
osx:~ osx$ brew install freetype
Warning: freetype 2.9 is already installed
```

UPDATE- Running the below fixed my issue:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-38/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib /usr/local/lib/libMagickWand.dylib
```

Comment: looking into this now https://gist.github.com/dongyuwei/3668fcc69f557dd32c46

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dongyuwei/3668fcc69f557dd32c46 did not work. Still looking for solution

Comment: You would like us to fix some code we can't see? Come on, try a bit harder and show the code like StackOverflow requires.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The above post shows the relevant code issues. If you think you need more, what would you like? Literally, it posts every line with an issue. The issue is not the code, it's with the installed packages. More precisely a shared library not found. There is a dependency issue with the pip packages and has nothing to do with the code.